# Error with value count in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
INSERT INTO asterisk.llamadas (
            uniqueid, 
            fecha, 
            origen, 
            destino,
            tipo, 
            fechaInicioCola, 
            fechaRinging, 
            numeroRingings, 
            fechaAnswered,
            fechaHungup, 
            tiempoMensaje, 
            tiempoEnCola,
            tiempoProcesamiento, 
            tiempoRinging, 
            tiempoConversacion,
            cola, 
            agente, 
            duration, 
            srccanal, 
            dstcanal, 
            status
            )
SELECT 
    uniqueid, 
    fechaAccepting, 
    origen, 
    destino, 
    "Entrante", 
    fechaInicioCola, 
    fechaRinging, 
    numeroRingings, 
    fechaAnswered, 
    fechaHungup, 
    tiempoMensaje, 
    tiempoEnCola, 
    tiempoProcesamiento,
    tiempoRinging,
    tiempoConversacion
    cola, 
    agente, 
    duration, 
    srccanal, 
    dstcanal, 
    status 
    FROM asterisk.entrantes;
```

And I've double checked that each field have something that match... but still getting the

```
Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: The problem is you can't see missing commas. Also, shouldn't it be `'Entrante'`, not `"Entrante"`?

Comment: Count the commas, you're missing one!

Comment: @Bohemian nope, it shoulnd't or doesn't matter. Your comment is really rude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a comma after `tiempoConversacion` in your SELECT statement...

Answer (score 1):

It might just be that

```
tiempoConversacion
```

should be

```
tiempoConversacion,
```

(mind the comma :) )